# Editing YAML with user input via PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, yaml, pysimplegui

Im making great progress with my mini project. After reading a bit and looking at examples, I came up with this code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import yaml
from yaml.loader import SafeLoader
import os


working_directory = os.getcwd()

layout = [
    [sg.Text("Shoose your yaml file:")],
    [sg.Text("input1", size =(15,1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text("input2", size =(15,1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.Text("input3", size =(15,1)), sg.InputText()],
    [sg.InputText(key="-FILE_PATH-"),
    sg.FileBrowse(initial_folder=working_directory, file_types=[("YAML Files","*.yaml")])],
    [sg.Button("Submit"), sg.Exit()],
    [sg.Multiline(size=(40,20), key='-Multi-')
]]

window = sg.Window("File Loader", layout).Finalize()

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break

    elif event == "Submit":
        file_path = values["-FILE_PATH-"];
        with open(file_path) as f:
            data = yaml.safe_load(f)
            cur_yaml = yaml.safe_load(f)
            cur_yaml["testfield"].update(values[0])

        if cur_yaml:
            with open(file_path, 'w') as  f:
                yaml.safe_dump(cur_yaml, f)

          

window.close()
```

The program opens a window. I will browse for a yaml to edit. User will then enter string for 'input1', 'input2', and 'input3'. To test this code, i just want to update the 'testfield' by adding the value from 'input1' . Everything works good until I hit 'submit' and returns the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yaml_gui.py", line 32, in <module>
    cur_yaml["testfield"].update(values[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Guidance to what I should do or what im doing wrong would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Looks to me like cur_yaml is None

Comment: hi xdhmoore, how can I pass the value from 'input1' to the cur_yaml? I thought it was by using (values[0]) but that doesn't seem right because of the error.

Comment: Sorry I don't know the framework you're using, but I am assuming the problem is with the `cur_yaml["testfield"]`. If it was with `values[0]` I think you would have gotten an error a few lines up when referencing `values["-FILE_PATH-"]`. So I think `cur_yaml` is `None`, best I can tell.

Comment: Actually, I think the problem may be that you are trying to `safe_load(f)` twice. Once the underlying file object reaches the end of the file, I'm not sure if it will read it again from the beginning like your code is trying to do. Can you remove the line `data = yaml.safe_load(f)`? That `data` variable doesn't seem to be doing anything right now...